# How to make 3D objects jump smoothly apart from each other upon click? Three.JS

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I'm very new to Three.JS and 3D web dev in general what I'm trying to do is mimic this action: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HWSTxPc8npk&feature=youtu.be&t=7s Essentially this is a set of 3D planes and upon click the whole stack reacts and gives space around the one that's clicked.

For now, my base case is 3 planes and figuring first out if I can click the the middle one, how do I get the others to jump back smoothly as if they were pushed rather than instant appear and disappear as they do now on the click of a button.

The long term goal is to have a separate button for every plane so that on click, the selected plane will have padding around it and the rest of the planes in stack move accordingly.

I've looked into Tween.js, and CSS3D but pretty overwhelmed as a newbie. Any tutorials or tips would be greatly appreciated!

```
// Our Javascript will go here.
        window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

        function onWindowResize(){

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        }
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 3, 3, 1 );
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
        var plane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        plane.rotation.y = -.7;

        var material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x0000ff } );
        var material3 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } );
        var plane2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material2 );
        plane2.rotation.y = -.7;
        plane2.position.x = 1;

        var plane3 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material3);
        plane3.rotation.y = -.7;
        plane3.position.x = -1;

        scene.add( plane, plane2, plane3 );

        camera.position.z = 5;
        function render() {
            requestAnimationFrame( render );
            // cube.rotation.x += 0.1;
            // cube.rotation.y += 0.1;
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }
        render();

        function clickFirst() {
        TWEEN.removeAll();
        var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(plane3.position).to({x: -2}, 1000).start();
        tween.easing(TWEEN.Easing.Elastic.InOut);
            render();
        }
    </script>
    <button onclick="clickFirst();" style="background-color: white; z-index: 9999;">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you share your code?

Comment: just added the code in progress which doesn't work. I don't think I understand how to use Tween properly. Thanks for replying!!

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to locate the 2 planes.

Second, you need to make the planes clickable:
https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_cubes
https://github.com/josdirksen/learning-threejs/blob/master/chapter-09/02-selecting-objects.html

Third, you should use Tween.js for the transition.
after picking the right plane, make a tween for the other planes with a tween, all to move on the same Axis:

example:

```
createjs.Tween.get(plane3.position.z).to(
                plane3.position.z + 100
            , 1000, createjs.Ease.cubicOut)
```

If you will add some code here after starting to implement i would be able to help more.

Comment: Thanks Lior for replying! I actually don't want the planes themselves to be clickable but rather they are being controlled by a separate button control. I added my current code in progress which isn't working. I don't think I'm grasping the understanding of how to use Tween.js with Three.js

Comment: Are you able to see the planes?

Comment: Yes I have 3 next to each other!

Comment: var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(plane3.position.x).to({plane3.position.x-2}, 1000).start();
        tween.easing(TWEEN.Easing.Elastic.InOut);
            render();
        }   I edited the code in the answer by your code

Comment: Thanks Lior! But when I tried to input that code(swapped out the var tween line for yours), my planes don't show up anymore

Comment: function clickFirst() {
   TWEEN.removeAll();
         var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(plane3.position.x).to({plane3.position.x-2}, 1000).start(); 
            tween.easing(TWEEN.Easing.Elastic.InOut);
    render();
   }

Comment: I fixed the code a little bit. i deleted the extra brackets. maybe now it will work for you.

Comment: Sorry Tlatis, maybe i'm not understanding.. why are you using createjs before Tween? is that arbitrary? what does that refer to?Thank you so much for your time. Still not working but at least planes show up?: function clickFirst() {
   createjs.Tween.get(plane3.position.z).to(
                plane3.position.z + 100
            , 1000, createjs.Ease.cubicOut)
           }

Comment: No, sorry, it is because im using typescript. i guess you dont have to write it. just check any example in  tween.js. you are wellcome. hope it will work for you.